Definition of closed immersion of locally ringed spaces
I just read on math stack program the definition of surjectivity of morphisms of sheaves and presheaves. I found they are quite confusing. In the following definition $X$ denotes a topological space and $\mathscr F,\mathscr G$ denote preheaves resp. sheaves on $X$.
First let us look at the definition for surjectivity of morphism of presheaves:

A morphism of presheaves $\varphi: \mathscr F\rightarrow \mathscr G$ is called surjective if $\forall U\subset X$ open subset, $\varphi_{U}:\mathscr{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{G}(U)$ is surjective.

And this is the definition for surjectivity of morphism of sheaves:

A morphism of sheaves $\varphi: \mathscr F\rightarrow \mathscr G$ is called surjective if $\forall U\subset X$ open subset, and $\forall s\in \mathscr G(U)$, $\exists U=\cup_i U_i$ open covering, such that $s_{Ui}$ is in the image of $\varphi_{Ui}:\mathscr F(U_i)\rightarrow \mathscr G(U_i)$ for all i.

I find the definition very confusing, because what I expect is that surjectivity of morphism of sheaves means surjection as morphism of presheaves but it is not the definition given above.
Now let us look at the definition of a closed immersion of locally ringed spaces: A morphism of locally ringed space $i: Z\rightarrow X$ is a closed immersion if

(1) $i$ is a topological closed immersion.
(2) The morphism $\mathscr O_X\rightarrow i_*\mathscr O_Z$ is surjective. Let $\mathscr I$ denote the kernel.
(3) The $\mathscr O_X$-module $\mathscr I$ is globally generated by sections.

Let $(X,\mathscr O _X)$ be a locally ringed space and let $\mathscr F$ be an $\mathscr O_X$-module. Then for each $s\in \mathscr F(X)$, there is a map of $\mathscr O_X$-modules $$\mathscr O_X\rightarrow \mathscr F\\
x\mapsto sx$$
Let $(X,\mathscr O_X)$ be a locally ringed space. A sheaf $\mathscr F$ of $\mathscr O_X$-module is called globally generated by sections if

There exists a set $I$, for each $i\in I $, $\exists s_i\in \mathscr F_(X)$ such that $$\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathscr O_X \rightarrow \mathscr F$$ is surjective. Where the map is such that the map between the summand assciated to $i$ and $\mathscr F$ is the map defined above.

My question is for $(2)$ of the definition of closed immersion of locally spaces we want to have surjection as map of presheaves or map of sheaves. They are quite different. And for $(3)$ I do not quite understand what globally generated by sections mean. Notationwise it seems to be a morphism of sheaves or presheaves (i.e. we write $\mathscr O_X\rightarrow \mathscr F$ instead of $\mathscr O_X(X)\rightarrow \mathscr F(X)$ hence looks like natural transformation between functors ) but I think it is only defined on global sections and hence only means surjection as a $\mathscr O_(X)$-linear map.


Surjectivity of $\mathcal{O}_X\to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ is as a morphism of sheaves. When considering what happens for a morphism of sheaves, "surjectivity as a morphism of presheaves" is too restrictive. For a map of sheaves, you really want surjecitvity to correspond to surjectivity on stalks, and certainly there are maps of sheaves that are surjective on stalks but not surjective as maps of presheaves - consider the exponential map from the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\Bbb C$ to the sheaf of nonzero holomorphic functions on $\Bbb C$.
You don't want that $\mathcal{I}$ is globally generated by sections, you want that it is locally generated by sections. Locally generated by sections means that for all $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U\ni x$ such that $\mathcal{I}|_U$ is globally generated by sections.
A map $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{F}$ is determined by the image of $1\in\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ and in fact maps $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{F}$ are in bijection with global sections of $\mathcal{F}$ (this is something you should go prove if you're unfamiliar with it). Therefore for any collection of global sections $\{s_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ there is a map $\bigoplus_I \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{F}$ so that $e_i\mapsto s_i$. The condition that the $s_i$ generate $\mathcal{F}$ is exactly equivalent to this map being surjective as a map of sheaves: $\{(s_i)_x\}_{i\in I}$ generates $\mathcal{F}_x$ as a $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module iff the stalk map $\left(\bigoplus_I \mathcal{O}_X\right)_x \to \mathcal{F}_x$ is surjective.


Sorry I still have a question. In the end you stated that ${(s_i)x}{i\in I}$ generate $\mathscr F_x$ as a $\mathscr O_{X,x}$-module is equivalent to the stalk map $(\bigoplus _I \mathscr O_X)_x\rightarrow \mathscr F_x$ is surjective and it is equivalent to that $s_i$ generate $\mathscr F$. What does $s_i$ generate $\mathscr F$ mean?  Why is it equivalent to the map of sheaves is surjective? Is it just defined to be equivalent or some statement that I need to prove?

The definition for "a collection of global sections ${s_i}_{i\in I}$ generates $\mathcal{F}$" is that ${(s_i)x}{I\in I}$ generates $\mathcal{F}x$ as an $\mathcal{O}{X,x}$-module for all $x\in X$. The equivalence of ${(s_i)x}{I\in I}$ generates $\mathcal{F}_x$ for all $x$ and $\bigoplus_I \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{F}$ surjective is a quick proof.

Then if I am not mistaken the definition that $\mathscr F$ is globally generaeted by sections just means induced maps on stalks are surjective?

Yes, which is equivalent to surjectivity of the map $\bigoplus_I\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{F}$.

Thanks for yourhelp :)
